# is it correct way to make commit when 10 record are fetched?

Tags: oracle

To avoid data lose I just want to force my query to apply commit when 10 records are fetched 
, so is it correct way to make commit when 10 record are fetched ?

```
begin
  for i in 1..10
  loop
    insert into table_name
      select A.column1, A.column2,
             A.column3, A.column4,
             B.column1,B.column2,
             B.column3,sum(B.column4) as Namecolumn 
        from table1 a,table2 b
       group by  A.column1, A.column2,
                 A.column3, A.column4,
                 B.column1, B.column2,
                 B.column3
  end loop
  commit;
end;
```

Comment: How many total records you have loop over? And, how will you know which records have already been inserted in subsequent loop iterations?

Comment: What kind of "data lose" you're trying to avoid? It's hardly possible to advice anything when you don't explain the original task/issue.

Comment: if the conection time out..

Comment: If there is a risk of a connection time-out before your process completes you might want to think about scheduling the process.

Comment: okay im not fanna make commit for each 10 record coz this will dumm m code... its just an example so if thats possible pls let me know how to do it... thank you all

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't make sense to do that. It leaves you with incomplete business transactions in the system that you then have to rollback or complete manually, and slows performance. Commit at the end of every complete business transaction only.